# Replace menu links with # and add name to its li

Tags: functions, menus, javascript, jquery

I have a wordpress menu:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu-categorias',
    'container' => 'ul',
    'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav dragscroll' ) );
?>
```

Which outputs this:

```
<ul id="menu-menu-categorias" class="navbar-nav dragscroll">
  <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-8 nav-item fadeIn">
    <a href="http://website.test/category/ux/" class="nav-link">Ux</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-9 nav-item fadeIn">
    <a href="http://website.test/category/editorial/" class="nav-link">Editorial</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want the URLs of the `nav-items` to be replaced with `#` and to add the name of the category (in lowercase) to its `li` class . So the menu output should be like this:

```
<ul id="menu-menu-categorias" class="navbar-nav dragscroll">
  <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-8 nav-item fadeIn ux">
    <a href="#ux" class="nav-link">Ux</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-9 nav-item fadeIn editorial">
    <a href="#ux" class="nav-link">Editorial</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried adding this but I don't get anything changed:

```
function lb_menu_anchors($items, $args) {
  foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
      if ($item->object == 'custom' && substr($item->url, 0, 1) == '#') {
          $item->url = site_url() . $item->url;
      }
  }
  return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'lb_menu_anchors', 10, 2);
```

Any help to achieve these two things?

Comment: You can do this manually, by adding custom links, but I guess you are trying to just filter category term items?

Comment: Yes, I want to filter the category terms, not put the client into the position of doing this manually

Comment: You should be able to do this with a custom nav walker ([docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/)), have you tried that already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the URLs of the `nav-items` to be replaced with `#`

You can use the [`nav_menu_link_attributes` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/) to set the custom `href` value like so:

```php
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function ( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    if ( 'menu-categorias' === $args->theme_location && 'category' === $item->object ) {
         $atts['href'] = '#' . get_term_field( 'slug', $item->object_id );
    }

    return $atts;
}, 10, 3 );
```

> and to add the name of the category (in lowercase) to its `li` class

For that one, you can use the [`nav_menu_css_class` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/) whereby the "name" here is the term/category slug:

```php
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', function ( $classes, $item, $args ) {
    if ( 'menu-categorias' === $args->theme_location && 'category' === $item->object ) {
         $classes[] = get_term_field( 'slug', $item->object_id );
    }

    return $classes;
}, 10, 3 );
```

And note that, in my examples, I checked if the `theme_location` is `menu-categorias`, and I also assumed your menu items are all categories (i.e. terms in the `category` taxonomy).

### Alternate Solution

Use a custom walker by extending the [`Walker_Nav_Menu` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) and edit the `start_el()` method which generates the `li` element output (`<li><a></a></li>`). See an example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#comment-207).

Comment: works perfect, thank you for the solution and explanation :)